# "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon ...." when running docker on Ubuntu/WSL

Tags: lubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run docker in WSL (Windows 10) using the command `sudo service docker start`, and it shows:

```
 Starting Docker: docker
```

but when I run `sudo docker images`, it tells me:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello. So to be clear you will have Windows 10 with WSL running on top of that and now you want Docker running on top of WSL? I have to ask why?

Comment: Because I have some aws Credential access that did not work on windows

Comment: Sorry that does not explain why you are not running the Docker on windows instead of building this tower. Docker is a container what will be running in it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  What Ubuntu release are you using on WSL, and can you provide more detail on how you installed it and Docker?  Thanks!

Comment: It also might be useful to include the output of `ps n -efH` to see if the daemon is still running.

Comment: I am using wsl1 and I installed docker follwing this link https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9

Comment: this the output for ps n -efH                                                                                                                         UID   PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
       0     1     0  0 15:47 ?        Ssl    0:00 /init
       0     6     1  0 15:47 tty1     Ss     0:00   /init
    1000     7     6  0 15:47 tty1     S      0:00     -bash
    1000    95     7  0 15:47 tty1     R      0:00       ps n -efH

Comment: WSL is a Microsoft(tm) product.

Comment: @Yafaa Please edit your question with additional details rather than entering them as comments.  Also, you still haven't answered what *Ubuntu* release you are using.  Please include the output of `cat /etc/os-release | grep -i version` as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @Yafaa Also remember to tag people in replies using the `@username` style so that we get notified when you reply!  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It comes from nftables used instead of iptables 
I found this solution 
`sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy` 
from these threads: 
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/4872 
https://patrickwu.space/2021/03/09/wsl-solution-to-native-docker-daemon-not-starting/

Comment: Just a heads-up for readers that this is specific to Ubuntu 22.04 (really, I believe 20.10)  with WSL.  The OP never responded on which version they were using, but most readers who find this will experience this on Docker Engine with Ubuntu 22.04 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after a power outage. If it's the same problem that happened to me, then maybe your `settings.json` for Docker has been corrupted.  To fix:

- Move `%AppData\Docker\settings.json` (typically `C:\Users\<user_user_profile>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`) to a safe location for backup
- Restart Docker Desktop
- If this corrects the issue for you, you can delete the backed-up `settings.json`.  If not, you can restore it to the previous location.

Comment: Good info - Thanks!  Note, however, that most users that have this error are experiencing it due to the `iptables` issue mentioned in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406159/1165986), so I would personally recommend that they try that first.  However, this is a great "second step" if that doesn't work.  Also, the `iptables` issue will likely go away over the long-term, as the WSL2 kernel supports `nftables`.  So it's definitely nice to have an alternative cause to look at!

Comment: Also just realized that this question was specific to Docker *Engine*, whereas your answer is for Docker *Desktop*.  But that's still useful/helpful info for users of Docker Desktop, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**This fix worked for me :**

- Run `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables`
- Enter **1** to select **iptables-legacy**
- Run `sudo service docker` to start Docker